# Front strut alignment issues in i20?

Tags: springs

Sir, my car i20 front struts shockers are aligned perfect 90 degree with respect to ground when steering wheel is at normal or 0 degree position. However, the left shocker slanted bit about 30 degree approx with respect to its original vertical position when the steering is full turned to left. The same is for the right shocker when fully turned right. Is this change in vertical alignment normal??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are describing a correctly functioning steering / suspension system.

The change in angle is due to the combined effects of caster, camber and kpi (king pin inclination) and Ackerman steering angle.

These are designed to control the driveability of the vehicle during changing road conditions and speeds.